# Softphone Integration Appending on to URL

Tags: screen-flow, debug, softphone, call-center

We have a softphone popup configured in our FSC org. The process of redirecting to the calling user works fine.

However, when the user clicks on a callers profile from the popup, it appends the url from
'*/lightning/r/Account/{recordID}/view' to '*/lightning/r/Account/{recordID}/view?channel=OPEN_CTI'.

The ?channel is causing a screen flow to not popup on the UI. If we try via flow debug, the error does not exist.

The screen flow that is not working correctly is accessed via a button and we can see that the data is passing properly in the debug logs.

Thank you!